# assign driver with wpa_supplicant

Tags: wireless, drivers, server

Ubuntu server. I have a AR93xx wireless network adapter. I'm trying to use wpa_supplicant to connect to my home network. I run this:
`sudo wpa_supplicant -D ath9k -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa.conf`
The device is at wlan0 and the wpa.conf file is located there. Here's the conf file:

```
network={
    ssid="Enkidu"
    psk="mypasscode"
    #psk=hashed number not sure where it came from commented out
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    #proto=RSN WPA 
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

Message from wpa_supplicant: `wlan0: Unsupported driver 'ath9k'`

I'm changing my approach as I go. The driver is loaded, `iwlist wlan0 scan` shows all the local networks.

Next I edited the .conf file, un-commented the hashed password(my network passwords are AES encrypted, I read that in the router GUI). Then I went into the /etc/network/interface file and edited it like this:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf
```

Now when I run `wpa_supplicant -D ath9k -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa.conf` I get what looks like the correct feedback. Hooray! On to the next step.

So, now I'm stuck. I tried `sudo dhclient -r` and sudo dhclient wlan0` to see if that was needed to release the previous wired connection. Not sure what to do next.
Any help would be appreciated.

I rebooted the system and it connected to the system.

Answer (score 0):

wpa_supplicant does not directly use wireless device drivers,
and the version of Linux kernel being used is important.
Check output from running `wpa_supplicant` in a terminal
for its supported drivers.

Older kernels and drivers expect wpa_supplicant -Dwext;
newer kernels and drivers are cfg80211-based.
Look for cfg80211 when running:
lsmod | grep ath9k

wpa_supplicant in Ubuntu 14.04.2 uses -Dnl80211
to communicate with cfg80211.